# Fill middle of video with repeating a single frame in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have 49 rendered frames of png. I convert these frame to a video using`ffmpeg`:

`ffmpeg -r 24 -f image2 -s 1920x1080 -i %04d.png -vcodec libx264 -crf 25  -pix_fmt yuv420p test2.mp4`

However this just makes a sequence of all the frames. Now I try to achieve the following sequence:

```
frame 1...24 - frame 25 - frame 26...49
```

When frame 25 need to be repeated for 120 frames. Is this possible with `ffmpeg`?

It would be even better if it is possible to achieve:

```
frame 1...24 - frame 25 - frame 24...1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're working with the 50 frame sequence,

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i %04d.png
 -filter_complex "[0]trim=end_frame=25,split=2[fo][re];[fo]loop=118:1:24,setpts=N/24/TB[fo];
                    [re]reverse,setpts=N/24/TB[re];[fo][re]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0"
 -c:v libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p   out.mp4
```

`[0]trim=end_frame=25` --> keep the first 25 frames. Frames are numbered starting with 0.

`split=2[fo][re]` --> have two copies of this trimmed segment

`[fo]loop=118:1:24` --> Loop the single frame `1` at the end `24` `118` times. So there's 119 instances of the last frame.

`setpts=N/24/TB[fo]` --> long story short, ffmpeg is meant to work with timed media, so this filter is to make sure the segment now with the loop has smooth, continuous timestamps. `24` is the framerate of the input.

`[re]reverse` --> reverse the 2nd copy of the trimmed segment.

`setpts=N/24/TB[re]` --> same as above.

`[fo][re]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0` --> join the two segments - the looped one, and the reversed one. Since the 25th frame is the first frame of the reversed sequence, there's 120 instances of the 25th frame.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However the out.mpg only shows the start and end but misses the repeating of the single frame. Any thoughts?

Comment: Need to see full console output.

Comment: I've pasted the output at https://pastebin.com/gp4P6uCJ I needed to slightly change the length to 12 frames. So it has become 1..12 - 12 - 12..1

Comment: In loop, change 3rd value to 11. And change the 12 to 24 in setpts.